# make list items invisible in Alert Dialog

Tags: android, android-listview, android-dialog

I have create a alert dialog using following code and insert a list items inside it

now i want to make this item invisible or remove inside a dialog , is that a way to do it

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
final View directionEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.contact_dialog, null);                  

title.setText(contactStore.getContactName());
builder.setTitle(contactStore.getContactName());

/** Once I fill the item list , i want to make it invisible **/
builder.setItems(R.array.select_dialog_items, null);
```

item list is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="select_dialog_items" >
        <item>Command one</item>
        <item>Command two</item>
        <item>Command three</item>
        <item>Command four</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: Do you want to hide *one* of the items?

Comment: No , the whole list , but i can just put only one item in an array so eventually it will be same as hiding the whole list i guess

Answer (score 0):

use this: title.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: i tried your code but it does nothing and i guess title.setVisibility(View.GONE) may invisible the title not the List Items inside Alert Dialog